# Gmail Login in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I want to login in my app via gmail. I m using this code they open gmail for me. and they show screen after ward the do not redirect my app. Please help I am newer in iOS. On this screen there is code and written copy this code and switch to our app and paste here.Or is there any simple method for gmail login

```
static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"OAuth2 Sample: Google+";

NSString *kMyClientID = @"7-s.apps.googleusercontent.com";     // pre-assigned by service
NSString *kMyClientSecret = @"qD-L"; // pre-assigned by service

NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"; // scope for Google+ API

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;


viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                             clientID:kMyClientID
                                                         clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                             delegate:self
                                                     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:
                                                                                finishedWithAuth:error:)] ;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of last line:

`[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

There should be instance of your next screen view controller for example, next screen is homeViewController then:

`[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `GooglePlus.framework` for Authentication. Its quite easier. [Read more details for Integration](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)

You are missing `callback` which requires following settings in your application to handle.

`Step 1`
Add following method to your `AppDelegate.m` file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    //Handle callback here write a code
}
```

`Step 2` Set your `callback` url in `info.plist` refer screenshot for details.
[image]

after successful authentication it will be redirected to your application.